# APEX: How to automatically adjust item width when showing/hiding items?

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm building an application in Oracle APEX, and I'm running into a design problem.

I have a region with a dozen shuttles in a single row, and I need to show only 2 or 3 of them at any given time, based on the selection made in another drop-down list item.

To demonstrate the problem, and for testing, I built a brand new empty page to test with.
On this page, I created a Select-List item, which returns the number of shuttles to be displayed.

Then I created dynamic actions to show only the number of shuttles selected, and hide the rest.
So when the user changes the selection to a smaller number, some of the shuttles should be hidden in the browser, with no need to submit or refresh the page.

[image]

The dynamic actions work great, and hide the shuttles as expected.
However, the shuttles don't expand to fill the row.

This is a major problem, since the shuttles need more horizontal space in order to be *usable*.
When I hide the extra shuttles, I need the remaining shuttles to expand and fill the horizontal space in the row.

[image]

All of the shuttles are configured with `Automatic` column and colum-span options.

[image]

How do I make the shuttles expand to fill the horizontal space in the row, when I hide most of the other shuttles?
Could I re-render the items using a JavaScript dynamic action?

Answer (score 1):

Well i don't know an easy way to do it but you can try this:

The apex template is divided into 12 parts, so each item has its column span defined as a css class in its div container. You just need to change the class for the item to expand.

The class you can use is from `col-1` to `col-12`

The javascript you should use in your dynamic action should be something similar:

```
$( "#P_ITEM" ).parent().removeClass( "col-2" );
$( "#P_ITEM" ).parent().addClass( "col-6" );
```

this is an example of the html where the item is located:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting! Lemme tinker with that and see what happens.